# spring boot and datasource generation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, orm

I'am trying to do the ORM within Spring boot in STS 4 , so I create the entities then configure the application.properties like the following:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/basebanque

spring.datasource.username = root

spring.datasource.password = 

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.database= MYSQL

spring.jpa.show-sql = true 

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

The problem that I don't obtain any data source.
the console show the following:
[image: screen shot 1]

and:

[image]

Comment: The console looks ok. What doesn't work?

Comment: I can't find the tables (which are the java classes) in ma database.

Comment: and how do your entites look like? And where are they in the package structure?

Comment: the entities are javabeans and i put them in one package called entities under:src/main/java

Comment: You posted images of logs instead of plain text. Please don’t.

Answer (score 1):

Check which entities are scanned.

https://springbootdev.com/2017/11/13/what-are-the-uses-of-entityscan-and-enablejparepositories-annotations/amp/

By default, Spring Boot will enable entity scanning and look in the package (and its subpackages) where  @SpringBootApplication is located. If your configuration has entities in another package, use @EntityScan.